# My Excel 2007 xml map is dropping fields.

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I have been trying to use an xsd schema as a map in Excel 2007 to export an Excel (xlsx) file as xml. When I import my schema into Excel it seems always to be missing some fields. Does anyone know why this is?

Here is my schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="BatchMember">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Version" type="xs:decimal"/>
            <xs:element name="ClientId" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="PartnerId" type="xs:NCName"/>
            <xs:element name="BatchId" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:element name="BatchDateTime" type="xs:NMTOKEN"/>
            <xs:element name="MemCount" type="xs:integer"/>
            <xs:element name="ImportType" type="xs:NCName"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Member">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="CardNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:NCName"/>
                            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:NCName"/>
                            <xs:element name="MiddleName" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Surname" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Dob" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:NCName"/>
                            <xs:element name="Add1" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Add2" type="xs:NCName"/>
                            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="County" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:NCName"/>
                            <xs:element name="Email" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Phone" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="EmailContact" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="PostContact" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="SmsContact" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="PhoneContact" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Signed" type="xs:integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="StaffNo" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="DepartNo" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Arnotts" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Boyers" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Verify" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I upload it to Excel it does not seem to pick up the fields after the "Signed" field. It drops "StaffNo"..."Verify".

Here is a screen shot:

[image: Excel map]

Answer (score 0):

This was a false alarm. I had been amending the file in another directory. I had the map with too many levels. I reduced it down to 2 levels but was not looking at the corrected version, so was getting the original error. Apologies for this lapse.